# How to run insert statement as much times as select statement gives unique values?

Tags: select, auto-increment, firebird

DB Firebird.

I have the following statement

```
SELECT a.ID FROM CLIENTS a
```

And I want my INSERT statement into another table to use each of this value, something like

```
INSERT INTO BANKS (ID, NR, MONEY)
VALUES (
   gen_id(gen_name, 1), 
   "there should be client ID from the SELECT statement above", 
   3000
)
```

Can I achieve this with one statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you can use [`insert ... select`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-insert-select):

```
insert into banks(ID, NR, MONEY)
select 
   gen_id(gen_name, 1), 
   ID, 
   3000
from CLIENTS
```

If you have a trigger on `CLIENTS` that generates the ID on insert, or - Firebird 3 - `ID` is an identity column, then you can simplify this to:

```
insert into banks(NR, MONEY)
select 
   ID, 
   3000
from CLIENTS
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat unclear.  I'm more of a Sql Server person, but I believe Firebird supports the ROW_NUMBER function.  Following is a Sql Server example of using that function to auto-increment.

```
DECLARE @Client TABLE (ID INT);
DECLARE @Banks TABLE (ID INT,NR INT,MONEY DECIMAL(11, 2));

INSERT INTO @Client (ID)
VALUES (1),(2),(3);

INSERT INTO @Banks (ID,NR,MONEY)
SELECT 100 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS ID,0 AS NR,0 AS MONEY
FROM @Client;

SELECT *
FROM @Banks;
```

If you just want to insert into the Banks table a row for each corresponding row from the Client table, I would think a simple INSERT/SELECT statement would work:

```
INSERT INTO BANKS(ID, NR, MONEY)
SELECT ID, 0, 0 FROM CLIENT;
```

If your intent is to insert into BANK every row from client (where the client ID becomes the NR column on BANK) and you want to 'auto-increment' the ID on BANK, then this should work:

```
DECLARE @Client TABLE (ID INT);
DECLARE @Banks TABLE (ID INT,NR INT,MONEY DECIMAL(11, 2));

INSERT INTO @Client (ID)
VALUES (1),(2),(3);

INSERT INTO @Banks (ID,NR,MONEY)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS ID,id AS NR,0 AS MONEY
FROM @Client;
SELECT *
FROM @Banks;
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I brought confusion with that incremention, I edited my question. Basically I'm just asking how to make INSERT statement that would put every client ID there one by one.

Let's say I have 3 client IDs in table CLIENTS, then I would want to add to BANKS table 3 rows, and the second value of that row should have the client ID from from the CLIENTS table.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: You are missing several statement terminators (`;`) which makes reading your code rather hard (not al DBMS are forgiving as SQL Server regarding the lack f those ;)

Comment: Can't get it working with Firebird.

I'm trying something like INSERT INTO BANKS (ID,NR,MONEY) 
VALUES (
gen_id(gen_name, 1), 
SELECT r.ID FROM CLIENTS r,
3000
)
and obviously the bad line is SELECT...

Comment: I guess my Sql Server template example was not enough to get you going.  I don't have Firebird, but my Internet searches regarding what Firebird supported seemed to indicate my general idea would work.  I guess you'll need to wait for a 'Firebird' expert to chime in :(

Comment: if you're using generic insert/select syntax, you wouldn't have VALUES anything.  Take a look at my final example and you won't see VALUES.

Comment: Doing DECLARE outside of a stored proc or trigger is peculiar to SQL server; it's not something you find in most SQL implementations (nor is it standard). Firebird does, however support sequences, and the `INSERT..SELECT` form so this should be easily possible - something like `INSERT INTO BANKS (id, nr, money) SELECT gen_id(gen_name, 1), a.id, 3000 FROM clients a`.

Comment: Thank you all, @DaveJones' answer is exactly how it should look like on Firebird.

Comment: @DaveJones - you should post your comment as an answer and that really should be the accepted answer - not mine - i was rambling all over the place ;)

Comment: Using `ROW_NUMBER()` to generate ids is not advisable, it can (will) result in duplicates when concurrent inserts occur.